# Problema con git: fatal: bad config line 1 in file .gitconfig

Tags: git

No estoy pudiendo utilizar el `git` de manera local en mi macbook. No puedo hacer ningún movimiento por la terminal porque a todo me tira el mismo error.
En teoria esta instalado:

```
 $ git --version
 git version 2.15.0
```

pero todo me tira el error:

```
fatal: bad config line 1 in file /../.gitconfig
```

¿Alguna recomendación para tratar de solucionarlo?
¡Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al menos adjunta el archivo en el que ocurre el problema para ver cuál es la causa. ¿Cuál es el contenido del archivo por el cuál `git` te tira el error? ( `/Users/...`)

Comment: probaste reinstalar git y inicializar la [configuración](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Inicio---Sobre-el-Control-de-Versiones-Configurando-Git-por-primera-vez)

Comment: ahi subi una captura. gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en el archivo de configuración de `git` que se encuentra en `/Users/jeremiasrotondaro/.gitconfig`.

La forma más fácil de restablecer la configuración es simplemente borrando el `.gitconfig` y configurando tu usuario y contraseña nuevamente. Puedes hacerlo usando el comando:

```
rm /Users/jeremiasrotondaro/.gitconfig
```

O bien manualmente, usando la interfaz gráfica de tu sistema operativo.

Comment: Perfecto, entonces me inclinare por esa opción. Muchísimas gracias Jaime !

Comment: Me haces saber si te funcionó.

Comment: Si, funciono ! Millón de gracias!

Comment: La opcion de usar el comando "rm" seguido de la ubicacion de mi archivo .gitconfig me funcionó a la perfeccción, supongo que no hay tanta información al respecto de como solucionarlo porque pueda que para muchos a los que le haya pasado lo hayan solucionado sin mucho problema ni ayuda al ser en teoria "básico" asi que, gracias nuevamente a mi me ayudo muchisimos Saludos!